# how combine multiple query (selected statment) in my case?

Tags: php, mysql

The first query gives me required fields to table (`klass`, `Liikmenimi`, `synniaeg`, `Tiim` etc. )

```
 query("
   SELECT klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, TIME(`finish`) AS finish FROM bc2014 T1 
   INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
   WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)' ");
```

in phpMyAdmin with:

```
select timediff(time(finish), time(start)) AS aeg FROM bc2014aeg
```

gives me the required results for "time" in table

How can I merge these two  - in my case?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should just be able to add the fields into the select part of the statement

```
 query("
   SELECT 
     klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, 
     TIME(`finish`) AS finish,
     timediff(time(finish), time(start)) AS aeg
  FROM bc2014 T1 
   INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
   WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)' 
 ");
```

Comment: Thnak's @Ian Kenney You example is copy paste, at it's works like charm ;)

Comment: may be you can help my with next step as well ? 
now I Have time, but how can I find the difference between leader and Dif. between previous

Comment: start a new question and include a link to this one

Comment: @ Ian Kenney new question is [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894549/find-difference-between-leader-and-previous-in-results-table/29894988?noredirect=1#comment47913739_29894988)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL UNION operator allows you to combine two or more result sets from multiple tables into a single result set. The syntax of the MySQL UNION is as follows:

```
SELECT column1, column2
UNION [DISTINCT | ALL]
SELECT column1, column2
UNION [DISTINCT | ALL]

…
```