# Find Difference between leader and Previous in results table

Tags: php, mysql

Edited: (added table example)

With your help guys I'm in this place that I have information in table ( Name, team, start time finish time and even time between these two. thanks @Ian Kenney ;)
[solution to find time between start & finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891813/how-combine-multiple-query-selected-statment-in-my-case)

now how can I calculate and display on page difference between leader and difference between previous.

Current working query is :

```
        query("
          SELECT 
     klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, 
     TIME(`finish`) AS finish,
     timediff(time(finish), time(start)) AS aeg
  FROM bc2014 T1 
   INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
   WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)'
   ORDER BY aeg");
```

and output is something like that : 
[image]

table looks like this:

```
    echo "<tr><th>koht </th><th>klass </th><th>Liikme nimi </th><th>Synniaeg</th><th>Tiim</th><th>Start</th><th>Finish</th><th>Time</th><th>Dif.Leader</th><th>Dif.Previous</th><th>km/h</th></tr>";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

$timestamp = strtotime($row['synd']);
 print '<tr>';
  print '<td>' .$row["ranking"].'</td>';
 print '<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
   print '<td>'.$row["nimi"].'  '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].'</td>';
     print '<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["teamnimi"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["start"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["finish"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["aeg"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["difleader"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["difprev"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["speed"].'</td>';
 print '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: try date_diff function

Comment: @ Sundar Bons some example is more then welcome ;) I'm quite "green" with this ;)

Comment: show the code that loops through each row also please

Comment: sorry @Ian Kenny the loop as added

Answer (score 0):

```
$date2 = date_create($date2InString);
$date1 = date_create($date1InString);
date_diff($date2, $date1)->format('%h %i %s' );
```

for more formats:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

below code should do what you asked for

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['synd']);
 print '<tr>';
  print '<td>' .$row["ranking"].'</td>';
 print '<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
   print '<td>'.$row["nimi"].'  '.$row["Perekonnanimi"].'</td>';
     print '<td>'.$date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp).'</td>';
    print '<td>'.$row["teamnimi"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["start"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["finish"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["aeg"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["difleader"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["difprev"].'</td>';
$date2 = date_create($row["difprev"]);
$date1 = date_create($row["difleader"]);
date_diff($date2, $date1)->format('%h %i %s' );
print '<td>'.$row["speed"].'</td>';
 print '</tr>';
```

Comment: I edited question and added my table example, can you show example with my data ;)?

Comment: i have updated my answer in past one. Let me know if it worked

Comment: this example seems don't work .. I don't have values difprev & difleader in MySQL thous values must find from table .. or in your case I don't understand how it's must display the values

Answer (score 0):

you can work out the diff from leader by remembering the leaders time, and the previous time as you run through the loop.

lets add an elapsed_time into the query

```
SELECT 
 klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, 
 TIME(`finish`) AS finish,
 timediff(time(finish), time(start)) AS aeg,
 finish - start as elapsed_time
FROM bc2014 T1 
INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
WHERE klass = 'DS1 (1 koera toukerattavedu al.14 a.)'
ORDER BY aeg
```

Then use this in the result set to calculate the time differences

```
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
//.....

  if(isset($leader_time)){
    print '<td>'. $row["elapsed_time"] - $leader_time .'s</td>';
    print '<td>'. $row["elapsed_time"] - $last_time .'s</td>';
  } else { 
    print '<td> </td>';
    print '<td> </td>';
  }
// ...
  if(!isset($leader_time)){ $leader_time = $row["elapsed_time"] ;} 
  $last_time = $row["elapsed_time"] ;
}
```

you can then use $leader_time and $last_time to calculate the two difference columns

Comment: Hi! @Ian Kenney I have experimented with a variety of options here, but I'm so "green" yet - and results is not workin table. 
Can you give example with my data how I can use your explanations.

Comment: Seems I must do some paus,  Surely I'm not so stupid, but I don't find riht way to use this ;)

Comment: PS! your last "SELECT" gives this output elapsed time quite long ;) - in table first start is time.. finish is Timestamp [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbj1v6fit1g11e5/Screenshot%202015-04-27%2020.49.05.png?dl=0)

Comment: hi @ Ian Kenney, can you show me precise example with my data where what must be to display dif with leader and dif with prev.

Comment: with your example display like that [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rj8ududexuij3op/Screenshot%202015-07-10%2010.34.09.png?dl=0)
my code looks like : [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tkfbwssgpm9n75/Screenshot%202015-07-10%2010.39.28.png?dl=0)