# Time Difference between the leader and the next And Diff. between previous

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Once I asked this question, but I did not get working solution for that.
I have table of reults
Visual like that:
[image]

query:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("  
      SELECT 
T1.bc2014_id, klass, nimi, synd, teamnimi, start, 
 TIME(`finish`) AS finish,
 timediff(time(finish), time(start)) AS aeg,
 finish - start as elapsed_time
FROM bc2014 T1 
INNER JOIN bc2014aeg T2 on T1.bc2014_id = T2.bc2014_id
WHERE klass = 'DCM (koerakross, mehed al. 14 a.)'
ORDER BY aeg ");
```

PHP table:

```
print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>  Class DCM </th></tr>";
print '</table>';

print '<table class="mytable7">';
echo "<tr><th>Place</th><th>ID </th><th>clas </th><th>Name </th><th>Start</th>
<th>Finish</th><th>Time</th><th>DifLeader</th><th>DifPrevios</th><th>KM/h</th></tr>";
while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {

print '<tr>';
print '<td>'.$row["ranking"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["bc2014_id"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.removeParanthesis($row["klass"]).'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["nimi"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["start"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["finish"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["aeg"].'</td>';

print '<td>'.$row["difleader"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["difprev"].'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row["speed"].'</td>';
print '</tr>';

}  
print '</table>';
$results->free();
```

MySQL time table structure:
[image]

Info from MySQL time table:
[image]

I'm not able to run time difference between Leader and between Previous.
And the bonus to get work calculating the speed (km/h) when distance is let's say 15 km

At the end table should look like this
[image: final table here][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agto8.png)

Comment: so you want to calculate the the summary of difference between finish and start time for a user OR have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I want the table looks something like that [table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6nxadvyg5gdj2e/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2017.29.16.png?dl=0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Difference between leader and Previous in results table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894549/find-difference-between-leader-and-previous-in-results-table)

Comment: Ok so you want to get Difleader Difprevios and KM/h? if so then let me understand how you calculate DifLeader, DifPrevious and KM/h if I know that it will be easier to start some where. @DarkBee he write that the questions is asked once previously but he did not get an usable answer.

Comment: @maytham In my example I did it manualy - just for example

Comment: Hei!
It can not really be so difficult, any help!?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're struggling with this. If you want easy but dirty solution then add those 4 lines to your SELECT statement (after "finish - start as elapsed_time"):

```
if (@bestFinish <= finish, timediff(TIME(finish), TIME(@bestFinish)), '00:00:00') as difleader,
if (@previousFinish <= finish, timediff(TIME(finish), TIME(@previousFinish)), '00:00:00') as difprev,
@previousFinish := finish,
@bestFinish := if (@bestFinish > finish, finish, @bestFinish)
```

Comment: After 4 lines situation is like that [table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4cw9lvalzhm7syw/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2022.56.06.png?dl=0)

Comment: In phpMyAdmin  get something like this [php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w46q61oliq6lyg3/Screenshot%202015-07-24%2023.20.35.png?dl=0)